# Having an Init and Dispose State Inside a Stateless Widget? Is it possible? any alternate approach?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

So many senior developers tell me that using a stateful widget is very bad practice and one should always use a stateless widget.

The point of having a stateful widget for me is so I can call my View Model's init and dispose functions inside the initState() and disposeState() methods of the stateful widget.

let's say for example I have the following view model

```
class CounterViewModel extends ChangeNotifier{
     int counter = 0;
     
     void incrementCounter(){
         counter ++;
         notifyListeners();
        }

void initCounter({required int value}){
// Let's say this is the function I want to call in initState
counter = value;
notifyListeners();
}

void disposeCounter(){
// Let's say this is the function I want to call in disposeState
counter = 0;
}

}
```

Now this I can easily do using a Stateful Widget. but for Stateless Widget I don't know what to do. calling inside build can cause the initCounter method to be called again and again and I also will have to do manual dispose once I navigate back from desired screen.

There has to be a better solution out there which supports Stateless Widget. Can someone enlighten me? Thanks

Comment: you can use [this](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider)

Comment: Why is it a bad pratice??? It's useful (pun not intended) when needed, like in your case

Comment: @VincentDR a lot of senior devs tell me It's bad practice because it wastes a lot of memory. but they also don't give me a solution to my problem

Comment: its missleading, you should use stateless widget first, if you need state lifecycle, use stateful widget. the bad practice is when you dont know where to use setState, even stateless is expensive too, check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) widget, they explain it

Comment: @SayyidJ How do I use this for my use case? can you elaborate by giving an answer? Reading the documentation I don't see any change in using this or ChangeNotifierProvider. I still would not have init or dispose state

Comment: @JunaidTariq when you use setState, all @override build(context) function is rebuilding, from top to bottom, the top is where you call setState, then flutter discard all the widget without `const` keyword, and make new widget to memory, this is when `dispose` method usefull to release resources

Comment: @SayyidJ Thankyou for the suggestion. I do use Stateful Builder very frequently. So I guess the answer is use Stateful Widget for this use case?

Comment: @JunaidTariq stateful widget is ok, just becareful, when you call setState, even widget like `AnimationBuilder`, built in animation like tweenbuilder, is a statefulW and call setState on every tick, at screen rr cmiiw

Comment: You use `StatefulBuilder` a lot? Really? This is how that class starts: `class StatefulBuilder extends StatefulWidget`... do you not see how this is a bit silly? Your senior developers are just *wrong*.